# Javascript | Map to object by dot notation

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I currently have a string which is like the following `author.id`.

Essentially what I want to do is convert this string into an object. The first becoming a relationship and then the last being an attribute. However the list could actually become longer example:

`author.sites.id` which would then become the following object:

```
{
    author: {
        relationships: {
            sites: {
                attributes: {
                   id: 1
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There will always be a top level property on the object being `relationships` as that is the purpose of doing this, mapping it to a JSON API Spec POST request.

So the example of `author.id` would produce a object with the following properties:

```
{
    relationships: {
        author: {
            attributes: {
                id: 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So essentially all of the properties that are split by the `.` should be nested within a parent property of `relationships` and the last should always be `attributes`.

I know you could probably used reduce for this and I have created the following function based off other questions on Stack Overflow but it doesn't do the nesting correctly any doesn't have `attributes` as a property for the final object which is output.

This is the method which I made based off of other questions:

```
function mapToObject(object, index) {
    index.split('.').reduce(function (obj, i) {
        return obj[i];
    });
}
```

Another example based off real world is I have an array of strings...

```
[{ key: 'author.id', value: '1'}, { key: 'image.id', value: '1'}]
```

I am then going to loop through these and add them as an object property to a object which is predefined.

```
let mappedRelationships = {};
let relationships = [
    {
        key: 'author.id',
        value: 1
    },
    {
        key: 'primaryImage.id',
        value: 12
    }
];

relationships.forEach((relationship) => {
    mappedRelationships = {
        ...mappedRelationships,
        // This is where I would need to do the logic for the reduce
    }
});
```

The value of the relationshipsMapped var would be the following:

```
{
    author: {
        attributes: {
            id: 1
        }
    },
    primaryImage: {
        attributes: {
            id: 12
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What will be the value of `id`?

Comment: Can you add more information and examples please?

Comment: I've updated the question to have a better example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `reduce` and create an object with the key-value pair by splitting `key` in  relationship array.

```js
let relationships = [
 {
  key: 'author.id',
  value: 1
 },
 {
  key: 'primaryImage.id',
  value: 12
 }
];

let mappedRelationships = relationships.reduce((acc, {key, value}) => {
let [k, v] = key.split('.');
acc[k] = {attributes: {[v]: value}};
return acc
}, {});
console.log(mappedRelationships)
```

You could use condition if string has 3 params

```js
let relationships = [
 {
  key: 'author.sites.id',
  value: 1
 },
 {
  key: 'primaryImage.id',
  value: 12
 }
];

let mappedRelationships = relationships.reduce((acc, { key, value }) => {
let arr = key.split('.');
let extra = arr.length > 2 ? arr.shift() : null;
let [k1, k2] = arr;
let relationships = { [k1]: { attributes: { [k2]: value } } };
return extra ? {...acc, [extra]:{relationships}} : {...acc, relationships};
}, {});
console.log(JSON.stringify(mappedRelationships))
```

Comment: This is perfect and really simple, however which I did forget to mention in the question (sorry!) is that it could be a list of things such as `author.sites.id` and this would give off the following object `{ author: { relationships: { sites: { attributes: { id: 1 } } } } }` I will update the question now, sorry.

Comment: no it will not consider `author`. will update the solution to consider that as well.

Comment: @tallent123 can there be `author.sites.id` as well as `author.id`?

Comment: there can be yes.

Answer (score 1):

You could

- create an array of keys with the wanted and dynamic parts,
- take the last key,
- reduce the keys and assign an object if the property has a falsy value,
- finally assign the value by taking the last key.

```js
function create(object, { key, value }) {
    const parts = ['relationship', 'attributes'],
          keys = key.split('.').flatMap((k, i) => [parts[i], k]),
          last = keys.pop();

    keys.reduce((o, k) => o[k] = o[k] || {}, object)[last] = value;
    return object;
}

var data = [{ key: 'author.id', value: '1' }, { key: 'image.id', value: '1' }],
    object = data.reduce(create, {});

console.log(object);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: Based on question change, Updated to support multipule levels

Using with `reduce`, `split` and destructuring.

```js
let relationships = [
  {
    key: "author.sites.id",
    value: 1
  },
  {
    key: "primaryImage.id",
    value: 12
  }
];

const updated = relationships.reduce((acc, { key, value }) => {
  const keys = key.split(".");
  let item = { attributes: { [keys.pop()]: value } };
  while (keys.length > 0) {
    item = {
      [keys.pop()]: {...item}
    }
  };
  return {
    ...acc,
    ...item
  };
}, {});

console.log(updated);
```

Comment: `id` is not hardcoded should be `key.split(".")[1]` and there is no point in splitting it twice. so one line won't work here.

Comment: @AZ_, You are right, I did not realise that. Thanks for your suggestion. Now I updated to take care of `n` levels.

Comment: OP needs the `relationships` in-between so while loop will also not work.